# If $f:[a,b]→\mathbb{R}$ is increasing then $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Prove that if $f:[a,b]→\mathbb{R}$  is increasing then $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ exists.

Since $f$ is increasing then I can find step functions $f_1(x),f_2(x)$ such that $f_1(x)\le f(x)\le f_2(x)$ and then assume such a function can only have a finite number of discontinuity points. Is there another simpler way using Riemann sums to show this besides using step functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(a)<f(b)$, then give $\epsilon >0$

Set $\delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}{f(b)-f(a)}$

Consider a partition $T$ st $d(T)<\delta$

Since $f$ is increasing in [$a,b$] then for each subinterval [$x_{i-1},x_i$] of the partition $T$ we have:

$w_i=M_i-m_i=f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})$ where $M_i=\underset{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}{maxf(x)}, m_i=\underset{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}{minf(x)}$ and $w_i$ is the oscillation of $f(x)$ over  [$x_{i-1},x_i$].

Therefore,

$\sum_{i=1}^nw_i(x_i-x_{i-1})<d(T)\sum_{i=1}^nw_i<\delta \sum_{i=1}^n\left [ f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}) \right ]=\delta\left [f(b)-f(a)  \right ]$

So $\forall\epsilon >0$,$\exists \delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}{f(b)-f(a)}$ for any partition $T$ st $d(T)<\delta$ we have

$\sum_{i=1}^nw_i(x_i-x_{i-1})<\delta\left [f(b)-f(a)  \right ]=\dfrac{\epsilon}{f(b)-f(a)}\left [f(b)-f(a)  \right ]=\epsilon.$

So $f$ is integrable over [$a,b$].

Comment: What is $d(t)$ and $d(T)$?

Comment: sr, that's my mistake. $d(T)$ is the diameter of the partition $T$. I have just edited.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: you're welcomed :D

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose a natural number $n$ such that $(b - a)(f(b) - f(a)) < n\epsilon$.

Let $P =\left\{x(0),\dots,x(n)\right\}$ with $x(k) = a + k(b - a)/n$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. Then $0 \le U(P,f) - L(P,f) = (b - a)(f(b) - f(a))/n < \epsilon$. The claim follows.

Comment: Hi. I've typeset your answer for you; I hope this is OK. I encourage you to learn $\LaTeX$ and typeset your future answers with it.

Comment: Thanks so much Potato. I am learning LaTex now.My work keeps me from learning this important tool.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A monotonic function has at most countably many discontinuities. Any function with countably many discontinuities is integrable.